# How to handle the ios::failbit correctly

Tags: c++, exception, stdin

I tried to make a program that takes the inputs until the -1 is entered and handles the inputs properly using exceptions.

It takes user inputs `FirstName` and `Age` and print the `FirstName` and increased age by 1. If the second variable is not an integer(age) then it should print `FristName` and `0`.

But my program gives me an unexpected output. How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

***Input format***

```
John 12

Michel 15

Alice Graz 11

Bob 15

-1
```

***Expected Output***

```
John 13

Michel 16

Alice 0

Bob 16
```

****My code****

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    string inputName;
    int age;

    cin.exceptions(ios::failbit);

    cin >> inputName;
    while (inputName != "-1")
    {
        try
        {
            cin >> age;
        }
        catch (exception ex)
        {
            age = -1;
            if (cin.fail())
                cin.clear();
            cin.ignore();
        }

        cout << inputName << " " << (age + 1) << endl;

        cin >> inputName;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using `cin.ignore()` like this

```
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

You have to include `<limits>` header file.

Comment: Thanks that works. but there's a warning warning: catching polymorphic type ‘class std::exception’ by value [-Wcatch-value=]
   catch (exception ex)

Comment: can you just explain what that line does and why passing such a numeric_limit together with '\n'. Thanks

Comment: try this catch statement instead `catch(std::ios_base::failure& faill)`

Comment: you can refer this https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: @Jacobe Prefer using [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) instead of cplusplus.com. It has a lot less errors and bad examples.

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo Noted. Thanks